# How to create 2 buttons Play , pause in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 buttons in the card, like the below.

```
<div class = "card">
   <button class ="play"> Play </button>
   <button class ="pause"> PAuse </button>
</div>
```

When I press `PLay` button, `Pause` should be enabled. `Play`  button should be disabled.

After Pressing `Play`,If I press `Pause` button, `Play` button should be `Enabled` and `Pause` button should be `disabled`.

The one thing, We cannot directly press the `Pause` button, without pressing the `Play` button.

How could I write a code to show the conditions `Play` and `Pause` in JS.

Could anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set by default `disabled="true"` for `.pause` button and continue with set `click` event for two buttons

```js
$(".play").on("click", function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true );
  $(".pause").prop("disabled", false );
})

$(".pause").on("click", function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true );
  $(".play").prop("disabled", false );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "card">
   <button class ="play"> Play </button>
   <button class ="pause" disabled="true"> PAuse </button>
</div>
```

If you don't have controll on your DOM and can't add `disabled="true"` for `.pause`, you can use `$(".pause").prop("disabled", true )` before define events

```js
$(".pause").prop("disabled", true );

$(".play").on("click", function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true );
  $(".pause").prop("disabled", false );
})

$(".pause").on("click", function(){
  $(this).prop("disabled", true );
  $(".play").prop("disabled", false );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "card">
   <button class ="play"> Play </button>
   <button class ="pause"> PAuse </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is the vanilla Javascript version.

Html:

```
<div class = "card">
   <button class ="play"> Play </button>
   <button class ="pause"> Pause </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const playButton = document.querySelector('.play');
const pauseButton = document.querySelector('.pause');

// By default make pause button disabled
pauseButton.disabled = true;


playButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  pauseButton.disabled = false;
  playButton.disabled = true;
});


pauseButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  playButton.disabled = false;
  pauseButton.disabled = true;
});
```

This will work.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/codersgyan/pen/wvdLZNR)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("play")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("play pause").html("&#9208; Pause");
      // Trigger Play event
    } else {
      $(this).toggleClass("play pause").html("&#9205; Play");
      // Trigger Pause Event
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <button class="btn play">&#9205; Play</button>
</div>
```

This retains the one button yet changes the Class and Content of the button as needed.

Symbol Reference: http://www.scrollseek.com/wd/html_symbols_complete.html